# Cómo eliminar alerta en consola sobre " Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: angular

tengo un array de contactos y cuando quiero saber si esta vacío el array hago esto:

```
  nothing(): boolean {
    if (this.contacts[0]) return false;

    return true;
  }
```

pero esto provoca un error en consola que dice:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined,

¿Cómo puedo hacer para evitarlo?

Comment: Debes declarar la variable **contacts** antes del constructor.

Comment: Gracias @DavElsanto lo arregló

Comment: `return this.contacts.length > 0`??

Answer (score 0):

No veo la necesidad de usar una función para esto, pero siguiendo tu código puedes hacer algo con la validación del [operador de encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Encadenamiento_opcional).

```
contacts?.length
```

```js
contacts= [];
function nothing() {
    return !contacts?.length > 0;
}

contacts= [0,1];
console.log(nothing(contacts)); // false

contacts= [];
console.log(nothing(contacts)); // true

contacts= null;
console.log(nothing(contacts)); //true

contacts= undefined;
console.log(nothing(contacts)); //true
```

Yo simplemente usaría la variable para validar si esta lleno o vació, sin la función

```js
contacts = [1,2,3];
if(contacts?.length > 0){ console.log('con datos')} else {console.log('vacio')}

contacts = [];
if(contacts?.length > 0){ console.log('con datos')} else {console.log('vacio')}

contacts = null;
if(contacts?.length > 0){ console.log('con datos')} else {console.log('vacio')}

contacts = undefined;
if(contacts?.length > 0){ console.log('con datos')} else {console.log('vacio')}
```